# Removing quotes and row number

Tags: r

I don't want row number as well as Quotes when I call a variable.
For example:

```
>aa<-"cc"
>aa
cc
```

I tried cat() but it's not assigning the value to another variable, immediately result will come and assigning NULL to the variable.
For example:

```
>aa<-"cc"
>bb<-cat(aa,"\n")
cc
>bb
Null
```

when I call `bb`, `cc` should come without row number and quotes.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the quotes?

Comment: `cat(aa,"\n")` seems to be doing what you want, right? If you just want this to print correctly, then don't reassign to `bb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you want to convert your string to a symbol:

```
as.symbol(aa)
cc
```

or

```
a.name(aa)
cc
```

But is you want to assign the result to a new variable you should define the symbol before, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Yes I want to assign this result to a new variable. how to define the symbol?